# Flutter build error: Dart 2.13.1 is incompatible with your dependencies' SDK constraints

Tags: flutter, dart, compilation, yaml

I am relatively new to Flutter, and don't seem to be able to figure this out.

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: app
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.16.0-80.1.beta <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_login: ^3.1.0
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.2.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.12
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  json_annotation: ^4.4.0
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.7
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

I did of course try to run $(flutter) pub get, update flutter channel to the latest master and dev, run $flutter packages pub run build_runner watch, but to no avail...

The dev channel in particular lists "Dart 2.16.0 (build 2.16.0-134.1.beta)" as a dependency tool, but I still get the same compile error.

Comment: Sounds like the Dart version you are running on your system is Dart 2.13.1? What does `flutter doctor` return?

Comment: flutter doctor seems ok: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.10.0-0.1.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1415], locale en-GB)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] VS Code (version 1.62.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!

Comment: What does `dart --version` say?

Comment: The error suggests that one or more of the package dependencies you list in pubspec.yaml has a dart SDK constraint that is not compatible with yours. Try `pub get --verbose` to see more detail on the offending dependency.

Comment: @julemand101 it logs: Dart SDK version: 2.15.1 (stable) (Tue Dec 14 13:32:21 2021 +0100) on "macos_x64".

Comment: Just got back to this project, with a fresh mind, and I quickly fixed the issue by changing the environment sdk to ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0". Thank you julemand101 and Bram for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got back to this project, with a fresh mind, and I quickly fixed the issue by changing the environment sdk to ">=2.15.1 <3.0.0".